# Need to setup a wordpress subpage for a Rails app (apps deployed on Digital Ocean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, dns, digital-ocean

I have a rails app deployed on Digital Ocean. I want to host a few side projects as subpages on Wordpress, again deployed on Wordpress.

Read about this quite a bit but couldn't find anything much helpful. [This article by Paul Arterburn](https://hackernoon.com/wordpress-inside-a-ruby-on-rails-app-c324fbf39ad8) was referred the most, however, it recommends using Flywheel.

Here's the exact setup I am looking at:

example.com -> Rails app deployed on Digital Ocean. Domain managed on DO as well.

Want to have example.com/blog as a Wordpress blog, deployed on a separate DO droplet.

I am unable to figure how to configure the DNS records (of example.com/blog) to point to the IP address of the wordpress droplet and the corresponding admin settings for WP.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dns settings don’t matter all that much in this case. You can either use the IP of the droplet or a temporary domain if DO gives you one from setting up the Wordpress droplet.

The magic is in the reverse proxy settings in your rails app to point to this IP/temp domain.

Here’s your situation described with a not-as-helpful answer, but perhaps you could reach out to the author if you’re still having issues: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/possible-to-host-blog-in-a-subfolder-on-a-different-droplet

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped. Had to go through nginx documentation - https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy but it's quite helpful and straightforward.

The only additional thing to do is to replace all internal links by the original domain.